# Could I export model trained with h2o to Java code?

Tags: java, r, production-environment, h2o

Could I export model trained with `h2o` to Java code when using `h2o` from level of `R` package ?

Comment: I think you can, just export the model from R, then import model to H2O Web, then generate the Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is exactly what the *POJO* is for. In your R script, if `m` is your model, then you can get the POJO with:

```
h2o.download_pojo(m, "/path/to/save/in/");
```

This will choose the filename, and create a java file in the directory you give. By default it will also download the jar file you need.

If saving to the local file system is not desirable, don't give a path (i.e. do just `h2o.download_pojo(m)`) and it will output the java class to your R session, where you could capture the output, and do something with that.

Also take a look at `h2o.download_mojo()`, which gives a different format. It is for tree models, which can get very big (in fact it only supports random forest, GBM and GLM currently).

More info on both POJO and MOJO here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/pojo-quick-start.html